# When RegisterEventBus " No service for type Autofac.ILifetimeScope' has been registered.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azureservicebus, event-bus

I am configuring service bus, as per code below. When I execute this code, it accuses this error that I do not know how to configure it. Please. me the bridge from where it comes or how to arrange it

```js
private void RegisterEventBus(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var subscriptionClientName = Configuration["SubscriptionClientName"];

            if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("AzureServiceBusEnabled"))
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, EventBusServiceBus>(sp =>
                {
                    var serviceBusPersisterConnection = sp.GetRequiredService<IServiceBusPersisterConnection>();
                    var iLifetimeScope = sp.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();
                    var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<EventBusServiceBus>>();
                    var eventBusSubcriptionsManager = sp.GetRequiredService<IEventBusSubscriptionsManager>();

                    return new EventBusServiceBus(serviceBusPersisterConnection, logger,
                        eventBusSubcriptionsManager, subscriptionClientName, iLifetimeScope);
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Yes, but I changed the way I set up.

Answer (score 3):

This documentation is what you want to check out, specifically for .net core v3+:

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer

Sample Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseIIS();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue while playing around. After my analysis, I figured out that the core problem is with the replacement of the default dependency injection container with Autofac's dependency injection container.

Ensure that you return AutofacServiceProvider in the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Exactly, this would be a probable problem so developers should add something like this to their ConfigureServices method   


    var container = new ContainerBuilder();
            container.Populate(services);

            AutofacContainer = container.Build();

            return new AutofacServiceProvider(AutofacContainer);

Answer (score 1):

I am learning event bus to follow shop, I met the same issue, at last, I found out the solution for the web-site [Mickaël Derriey's blog]
https://mderriey.com/2018/08/02/autofac-integration-in-asp-net-core-generic-hosts/.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await new HostBuilder()
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
        {
            // registering services in the Autofac ContainerBuilder
        })
        .UseConsoleLifetime()
        .Build()
        .RunAsync();
}
```

.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()) just help me complied the codes.